# SQL injecting a search form which uses boolean mode

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I'm testing a web app and I could get Mysql errors by inserting ' in the search field:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' in boolean mode)' at line 1
```

However, when I do the usual test, entering " ' and 1=1-- " to the search field, I get this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and 1=1--' in boolean mode)' at line 1
```

But this should have worked. I noticed that it appends " ' in boolean mode) " to every error it gives to me. My question is, what the problem is here and how I can get my statements performed, without getting this error?

Answer (score 10):

I find that `' or 1=1--` is useful in less than 1% of sql injection that I come across,  this payload is commonly seen in SQL Injection examples because it is a very simple statement.  The problem that you are most likely experiencing is that your comment is incorrect. The `--` needs to follow by a single space or it is not actually a comment, so `' or 1=1-- 1` is a comment that is compatible with many database types and it can survive a white-space trim.  There are plenty of other [mysql comments to choose from](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

A better SQL Injection test for a MySQL database would be: `' or sleep(10)/*`.  If the page takes 10 second or more to load then its vulnerable, then follow up with `' or sleep(0)/*` and it returns very quickly then you know it can be exploited with **blind sql injection**.

At this point I'm going to take that HTTP request and use [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org/) in wizard mode to exploit the vulnerability and dump the entire database.  SQLMap can also perform file-io under MySQL using `load_file()` and `into outfile`.  The interactive SQL shell mode is also very useful.  If you want to debug a SQL payload without using it on your target I suggest [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).